# How to sort the dictionary in the list by value, value is a number, key is a subject, there are multiple subjects and grades

Tags: python, dictionary

I have tried both list sorting and dictionary sorting. I don’t understand the dictionary sorting in this kind of list. The key sorting is sorted by name. How can I sort by the following results? I can extract Out the key and value, but how to turn the key and value into a dictionary

```
subject_score=[{'Mathematics': '56','Language': '48','English': '45','Chemistry': '12','Biology': '45'}] 
for i in subject_score
   for key, value in i.items():
       print(key,value)
dict1={}
dict2=sorted(dict1.items(),key=lamda dict1: dict1[1], reverse=False)
```

Comment: Please [provide your code as text as part of the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: unfortunately no. I keep getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having issues because your numbers are strings instead of ints. Removing the quotes around the numbers should fix everything.

```
subject_score=[{'Mathematics': 56,'Language': 48,'English': 45,'Chemistry': 12,'Biology': 45}]
dict2 = {key: value for key, value in sorted(subject_score[0].items(), key = lambda item: item[1], reverse = True)}
print(dict2)
```

returns:

```
{'Mathematics': 56, 'Language': 48, 'English': 45, 'Biology': 45, 'Chemistry': 12}
```

Comment: I don't think this was OP's question, but +1 since comparing numbers as strings will just compare the first non-itentical digit so it may cause unexpected behavior. It might be helpful to the OP to preserve the data types they're already using, so it might be preferable to change the sorting function to cast the numbers as integers instead of modifying the dictionary. So `key = lambda item: int(item[1])`